# unable to bind a signal to a slot in QT

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I just started with QT and I know the concept of signal/slot but in implementing it I have problem. 
take a look at my code :

```
#include "test.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
test::test()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

test::~test()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}



void test::fireslot(){

    qDebug("the slot fired");

}

void test::dosignaling(){
    QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(callslot()),this,SLOT(fireslot()));

}
```

note : I've added the Q_OBJECT macro and inherit from QObject in test.h

and here is my test container

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    //test t1();
    test *t2 = new test();


    t2->dosignaling();


    return a.exec();
}
```

code compile perfect but the nothing gonna happen . I'm not quite sure which part I've made mistake :-?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you have in `void test::dosignaling` connects a slot "fireslot" to a signal "callslot", but where are you **emitting** the `callslot` signal?

You should change your code and place your `QObject::connect()` in the constructor (or someplace else) and change your `dosignaling` method to:

```
void test::dosignaling()
{
    emit callslot();
}
```

Also, you haven't shown the header file but it should include a declaration of the callslot signal, like this:

```
class test
{
    ...
signals:
    void callslot();
};
```

Comment: And in the header, add slots: void fireslot();

Comment: yeah, well I figured he already did that since there's an implementation of fireslot